# Checking radio from another element click does not remove validation error

Tags: jquery, validation

As the title says, it appears that jQuery validation fails to recognize that a radio button has been checked, unless it is actually clicked.

Meaning, if you click another element and this click sets the radio to checked, the validation isn't aware.

[Here's a fiddle to show simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/4bz6xye5/) - Click submit, then click the radio button and all is OK, the error goes away. Then refresh, click submit, then click "click me" text and you'll see radio is checked but error does not go away.

Is there a workaround for this?

Here's the code:

```
<form>
    <div class="click">Click me</div>
    <input type="radio" name="options" class="radioB">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
</form>
<div id="error--holder"></div>
```

```js
$('.click').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.radioB').prop('checked', true)
});
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        options: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        options: "Whoops! Please indicate who.",
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $('#error--holder').html(error.text()+' <a href=#>Go fix it...</a>').fadeIn();
    },
    success: function(error) {
        $('#error--holder').fadeOut();
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        return false; // stop
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually validate the field

```
$('.click').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.radioB').prop('checked', true).valid()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/za6ocpyz/)

Answer (score 3):

Validate the form on click event

```
$('.click').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.radioB').prop('checked', true);
    $("form").validate();    
});
```